# How to Prevent Past-Due Notifications in Flutter Using Flutter Local Notification Plugin?

Tags: flutter, notifications

I'm using the Flutter Local Notification plugin in my Flutter app to schedule notifications for future dates and times. I need guidance on handling a scenario where, if the user restarts their device, notifications scheduled for past times should not be displayed when the app is opened.

What's the recommended approach for preventing past-due notifications from appearing when using the Flutter Local Notification plugin? For example, if a notification is scheduled for October 27, 2023, at 21:05, but the user restarts their device and opens the app at October 27, 2023, at 22:10, how can I ensure that the past-due notification doesn't show up?